# Update a MySQL database field data with HTML form and PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

So I am trying to update a database field using a html form and some PHP code, but I cannot get it to work, it throws no errors but does not update the field?, Im not sure if its because im also echoing that field on the webpage? All it seems to do is print the fail message.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <form method="post" name="update" action="updateform.php" />

    Description:

    <input type="text"  name="description" />

            <input type="submit" name="Submit" Value="update" />
    </form>

    </html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*****") or die("Connection Failed"); 
mysql_select_db("Days")or die("Connection Failed"); 
$description = $_POST['description']; 
$query = "UPDATE test SET description = '$description' ";
if(mysql_query($query)){ echo "updated";} else{ echo "fail";} ?>
```

My echo (working):

```
             <?php
include("include/session.php");
//connect to the server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","*****");

//connect to the database
mysql_select_db("days");

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hobby WHERE id = '1' ");

//ferch the results / convert results into an array

    WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

        $description = $rows['description'];

    echo "<div style ='font:15px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#cf5c3f     </h>'>$description";
    endwhile;






?>
```

Comment: It probably does throw an error. You just aren't looking for it. Use mysql_error() to see your sql error. FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Don't you need a `WHERE` for your `UPDATE` statement ?

Comment: try: `$res = mysql_query($query) or die("error: ".mysql_error());`

Comment: This is a very unsafe way to execute a SQL query, use PDO (http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead. If your update query would work, it would update **all** rows instead of just one. Use a `WHERE` statement to update just the rows you want to select.

Comment: it seems i have something wrong with my code? error: Table 'days.days' doesn't exist not sure why its repeating its self with a . in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Update query sample but i don't get your sql ..you missing your `where` clause

Comment: if where is missing it will update all rows , isn't it ?

Comment: A where clause is required always, if you want to update all rows you can use `WHERE 1=1`

Comment: Ive edited my code it seems I was missing a WHERE statment, however im still getting  error: Table 'days.days' doesn't exist, im not sure why its repeating days and adding a .

Comment: yup , but still in case if 'where' is missing , does it throws any errors ??

Comment: @Matt Since when is a `WHERE` statement required when updating all rows? (I'm interested, not sarcastic.)

Comment: AS I knew , "The **WHERE** clause determines which rows will be updated. It is an **optional** element of the UPDATE statement"

Comment: user3360311, now I look it up that may have been bad information, perhaps it's only with safe-updates enabled in MySQL workbench, my apologies!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WHERE` Condition whenever you try to update something to table.

Here's my code :

**test.html**

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="updateform.php" />

Name : <input type="text"  name="name" /> </br>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" />

</form>
</html>
```

**updateform.php**

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Enter Passwd Here","Enter db_name here"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "failed to connect " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{
    $query = "UPDATE `test_table` SET `name` = '$name' WHERE `cost` = 500"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 

    if (!$result) {
    die('Error' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Successfully updated";
    }
}
?>
```

To demonstrate I've created a database & table `test_table` with 3 field. (id,name,cost)
    
    
**This is the structure of my table :**

[image]

**Before executing the above script, our table contains this datas**

[image]

After executing the script, the **name in second row**  changes from `ramu` to `shiva` since we specified `cost` as 500 in `WHERE` Condition.

```
$query = "UPDATE `test_table` SET `name` = '$name' WHERE `cost` = 500";
```

[image]